# HttpServletRequestWrapper lose multipart inputs values

Tags: java, filter, xss

I'm trying to develop a XSS Filter. All works fine, but the wrapper is losing the multipart fields.

After the filter, in the controller, when I try to obtain the value of a multipart field always is empty.

I have the following wrapper:

```
public class XSSRequestWrapperMultipart extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

/** Constructor.  */
public XSSRequestWrapperMultipart(HttpServletRequest aRequest) throws IOException {
    super(aRequest);
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload( new DiskFileItemFactory());
    try {
        List<FileItem> fileItems = upload.parseRequest(aRequest);
        convertToMaps(fileItems);
    }
    catch(FileUploadException ex){
        throw new IOException("Cannot parse underlying request: " + ex.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * Return all request parameter names, for both regular controls and file upload
 * controls.
 */
@Override public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
    Set<String> allNames = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    allNames.addAll(fRegularParams.keySet());
    allNames.addAll(fFileParams.keySet());
    return Collections.enumeration(allNames);
}

/**
 * Return the parameter value. Applies only to regular parameters, not to
 * file upload parameters.
 */
@Override public String getParameter(String aName) {
    String result = null;
    List<String> values = fRegularParams.get(aName);
    if(values == null){
        //you might try the wrappee, to see if it has a value
    }
    else if (values.isEmpty()) {
        //param name known, but no values present
        result = "";
    }
    else {
        //return first value in list
        result = values.get(FIRST_VALUE);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Return the parameter values. Applies only to regular parameters,
 * not to file upload parameters.
 */
@Override public String[] getParameterValues(String aName) {
    String[] result = null;
    List<String> values = fRegularParams.get(aName);
    if(values != null) {
        result = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Return a {@code Map<String, List<String>>} for all regular parameters.
 * Does not return any file upload parameters at all.
 */
@Override public Map<String, List<String>> getParameterMap() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(fRegularParams);
}

/**
 * Return a {@code List<FileItem>}, in the same order as they appear
 *  in the underlying request.
 */
public List<FileItem> getFileItems(){
    return new ArrayList<FileItem>(fFileParams.values());
}

/**
 * Return the {@link FileItem} of the given name.
 * <P>If the name is unknown, then return <tt>null</tt>.
 */
public FileItem getFileItem(String aFieldName){
    return fFileParams.get(aFieldName);
}


// PRIVATE

/** Store regular params only. May be multivalued (hence the List).  */
private final Map<String, List<String>> fRegularParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();

/** Store file params only. */
private final Map<String, FileItem> fFileParams = new LinkedHashMap<>();
private static final int FIRST_VALUE = 0;

private void convertToMaps(List<FileItem> aFileItems){
    for(FileItem item: aFileItems) {
        if ( isFileUploadField(item) ) {
            fFileParams.put(item.getFieldName(), item);
        }
        else {
            if( alreadyHasValue(item) ){
                addMultivaluedItem(item);
            }
            else {
                addSingleValueItem(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean isFileUploadField(FileItem aFileItem){
    return ! aFileItem.isFormField();
}

private boolean alreadyHasValue(FileItem aItem){
    return fRegularParams.get(aItem.getFieldName()) != null;
}

private void addSingleValueItem(FileItem aItem){
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(aItem.getString());
    fRegularParams.put(aItem.getFieldName(), list);
}

private void addMultivaluedItem(FileItem aItem){
    List<String> values = fRegularParams.get(aItem.getFieldName());
    values.add(aItem.getString());
}

}
```

All relative to the fRegularParams works fine, but the fFileParams always appears as null in the controller.

What can I do to keep the values?

Regards

Comment: I have same problem any solution you got @Vcima

Answer (score 1):

If you see for `fRegularParams`, you are touching the `getParameter()` method of servlet lifecycle.

Here the parameters are already **initialized** in this phase.

For `fFileParams` you are trying to get params in constructor, which is **too early** considering lifecycle of servlet and filters.

Image for your reference:

[image: servlet lifecycle]

**Solution**:

Can you try with method `request.getParts()` instead?

You can try this approach and override

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2f20d6322b7a0fcbbaa80280849e7c31fc78d4a9/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java#L131

Which internally deals with request parts.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/2f20d6322b7a0fcbbaa80280849e7c31fc78d4a9/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java#L91

Answer (score -1):

Here "might" be your problem:

```
private boolean isFileUploadField(FileItem aFileItem){
    return ! aFileItem.isFormField();
}
```

It's returning the opposite response of the boolean value (check the `!`). Remove it and test if that works.

Only if the `FileItem.isFormField()` that you can get the form parameter data.

```
private boolean isFileUploadField(FileItem aFileItem){
    return aFileItem.isFormField();
}
```